# Sequelize can't access GCP Cloud SQL

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google cloud SQL instance and I want to be able to access it from my node.js application running locally on my machine.

I have enabled Cloud SQL instance access through public IP and created a network on GCP with my local machine IP and I have tested the connection in several ways:

1. MySQL Workbench
2. terminal
3. From my NodeJS application running locally using mysql2 to connect

All the above mentioned ways connected successfully and I can work on my cloud SQL instance as expected, the problem is when trying to allow my NodeJS app to connect using sequelize, I can see this error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeAccessDeniedError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

this is my connection code:

```
    host: 'XXX.XX.XX.XX',
    port: "",
    user: "root",
    password: 'password',
    database: "DB_NAME",
    dialect: "mysql",
    pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        }
   
    const db = {};              
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({ host, port, user, password });
    await connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${database}\`;`);
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, { dialect: dialect });
    
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    
    // // init models and add them to the exported db object
    db.orders = require("../../models/order.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
         
    db.sequelize.sync().then(function(){
              console.log('DB connection sucessful.');
            }, function(err){
              // catch error here
            
            });
```

Comment: You are trying to connect to localhost as root. Include the code that makes the connection.

Comment: I've updated the question, and also fixed the issue, sequelize is expecting me to pass the host to it.
It is not enough to pass the host to mysql connection, and it was working earlier as it seems to have a default value of localhost when host not explicitly passed to sequelize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Seems that I should pass the host as somehow it was considering host to be localhost when it is not explicitly specified

So this:

```
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, { dialect: dialect });
```

Should be updated to this:

```
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, { host: host, dialect: dialect });
```